# How to read stdout from a sub process in bash in real time

Tags: linux, bash, subprocess, stdout

I have a simple C++ program that counts from 0 to 10 with an increment every 1 second. When the value is incremented, it is written to stdout. This program intentionally uses printf rather than std::cout.
I want to call this program from a bash script, and perform some function (eg echo) on the value when it is written to stdout.
However, my script waits for the program to terminate, and then process all the values at the same time.

C++ prog:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        int ctr = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        {
                printf("%i\n", ctr++);
                sleep(1);
        }

        return 0;
}
```

Bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

for c in $(./script-test)
do
    echo $c
done
```

Is there another way to read the output of my program, that will access it in real time, rather than wait for for the process to terminate.
Note: the C++ program is a demo sample - the actual program I am using also uses printf, but I am not able to make changes to this code, hence the solution needs to be in the bash script.

Many thanks,
Stuart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you correctly observed, `$(command)` waits for the entire output of `command`, splits that output, and only after that, the `for` loop starts.

To read output as soon as is available, use `while read`:

```
./script-test | while IFS= read -r line; do
   echo "do stuff with $line"
done
```

or, if you need to access variables from inside the loop afterwards, and your system supports `<()`

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
   echo "do stuff with $line"
done < <(./script-test)
# do more stuff, that depends on variables set inside the loop
```

Comment: Plus the C++ program should be flushing its stdout after every write.

Comment: I agree! Even though the C++ program automatically flushes stdout after every line for all my compilers on my system, adding `flush()` would be good. If you cannot alter the program, try running it with `stdbuf -o0 ./script-test`.

Comment: I wouldn't count on stdio automatically flushing after a newline when the output is to a pipe instead of a tty.

Comment: Thanks - running the program using stdbuf -o0 has done the trick ;)

Answer (score -1):

You might be more lucky using a pipe:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

./script-test | while IFS= read -r c; do
    echo "$c"
done
```

Comment: This has a couple of unfortunate bugs; try http://shellcheck.net/ for diagnostics.